# Why two way of styling an element, is there an advantage?

Tags: html, css

I have seen a lot CSS stylesheet and there are at least two ways of styling an element I have come across. What I would like to know is how is styling a CSS element **different**, like the one below

```
a:link {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

<a href="#">Link</a>
```

to

```
.link {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

<a href="#" class="link">Link1</a>
```

What advantage does one have over the other?

Comment: Advantages? None. They're just two entirely different selectors. The first will select only unvisited `<a>` tags. The second selects anything with class `link`.

Comment: `.link` is simply class added to `a` tag. `a:link` means style for unvisited link. read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: Your examples aren't comparable. One is a pseudo-class that only applies to links, the other is a generic class that could be applied to any element.

Comment: @j08691, I guess I wanted to ask what is the advantage of using a class over a pseudo class. Could not think of anything fast enough so came up with this one. Sorry to disappoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no advantage in either case. They're performing two separate functions, so it's a bit of apples-to-oranges.

If you only want it to apply to **unvisited links**, use `:link`.

If you don't care if the link has been visited or not, use `.link`.

---

The `:link` selector applies only to links that have not yet been visited.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link):

> The :link CSS pseudo-class represents links (such as an anchor) that have not yet been visited.

---

The `.link` selector is a simple [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) will apply to any element that has the class `link` applied to it.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors):

> The CSS class selector matches elements based on the contents of their class attribute.

Comment: there is no advantage of using a class over the :link selector?

Comment: ...It depends entirely on what you're trying to do. The `:link` selector will not apply to links that have been visited. The `.link` selector will apply to anything that has `class="link"`, regardless of whether it's been visited or not.